# Right border not displaying on google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a `div` which contains an `a` with some border. See:

http://webnumbr.com/all

It works great in FF and IE, but why doesn't the right hand side render in Chrome? Is it invalid CSS? (testing in chrome OSX if that matters)

Comment: would you please attach the relevant css code?

Comment: Not just Google Chrome, it is WebKit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Test case:* Included so this question still makes sense after the content at the given URL changes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><style type="text/css">
div {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  margin: 3px;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid;
}
</style></head><body>

<!-- does not show right border -->
<div><span>With trailing space, no width </span></div> 

<!-- does show right border -->
<div><span>No trailing space, no width</span></div>
<div style="width: 40ex;"><span>With trailing space, has width </span></div>
<div style="width: 40ex;"><span>No trailing space, has width</span></div>

</body></html>
```

Verified in Google Chrome 4.0.266.0 (Official Build 33992) with WebKit 532.6.

Comment: Yikes. Chrome bug? Did you file it?

Comment: Since it is a bug in webkit, how should I change my HTML to achieve the same effect, but avoiding the bug?

Comment: @Paul: What do you mean? I gave three different examples that show the right border.

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell you the reason why this is happening, but I think I have a fix for you.  You have spaces padding your link content, and apparently Chrome isn't handling this very well.

If you remove the extra spacing around the contents of the `<a>` tags, the problem disappears (I did this in the Chrome inspector tool).  So, change:

```
<a href="pclark-hacker-news-karma"> 4,481 </a>
```

to:

```
<a href="pclark-hacker-news-karma">4,481</a>
```

Chrome must handle the space in an odd manner when dealing with a float (if you remove the float property on the `search_data` class, the border appears as well).

Comment: Nice find, was staring at it and couldn't see that.  I think it's related to .search_data being floated without specifying a width (add that and this also goes away).

Comment: Wow... am I doing something wrong (invalid, non-spec, non-standard, etc)? Is it a bug in chrome?