# chrome css problem: border (right) around link not displayed

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I have this small testcase: http://jsfiddle.net/sV8js/

You can see that in Chrome (tested on win7 11.0.696.68) the first 2 links right border is "cut off" and is not shown. FF and IE 7/8/9 seem to show it OK.

Browsershots: http://browsershots.org/http://top3skills.com/1.html

Also "buggy" on Safari (so it's webkit related?)

Anyone knows what's the problem with this approach or how to solve this? 
(or if I should report a bug to chrome) Any workaround that doesn't affect other browsers?

Also, my testcase is different from [Right border not displaying on google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082431/right-border-not-displaying-on-google-chrome) but maybe it's the same bug?

*Updated*: I don't want to use inline-block as IE7 doesn't support it and I'm finding this bug because I'm removing the inline-block I previously had there :) Also this is dynamic so it's not easy to add 
 after each link because some links can break to a new line, others don't... so I'm trying first to get the "right way" and then resort to more "tricky" ways.

Comment: Put display:block on them, or <br> after, and it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the containing *DIV* at a fixed width of **250px**. This is cutting off the edges. Also, you should add `display:inline-block;` to your *CSS* link class. This will make your link a *block* element while keeping it *inline*. It will also apply the padding you have asigned properly.

See updated link here **http://jsfiddle.net/sV8js/12/**

Dan

Comment: oops, sorry. I forgot to write that I don't want to use inline-block to maintain compatibility to IE7 (that's what I'm doing, removing inline-block, and that's how I found out this "bug") I'll update my original question stating this.

Comment: Hi AlfaTeK, It seems to display as expected in IE6&7. IE6&7 will ignore the block of inline-block and display links inline. See screen shot: http://i55.tinypic.com/15nvn9u.png

Comment: Tried again and I can manage with using inline-block even in IE7

Answer (score 1):

Try giving those links a `display: inline-block` or `display: block` property, as links are `inline` elements.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `display: block` to .referencesSkills